# Как разместить объект типа Picture в точке определенной (x,y) координатами?

Tags: java, android

Пробовал вывести вот так:

```
Picture[] mas_S = new Picture[10];
..................................
canvas.translate(200, 100);
canvas.drawPicture(mas_S[0]);
```

выводится, но со смещением, а мне надо вывести просто по указанным координатам (x,y)

Comment: А `со смещением` - Не одни ли тоже, что и `по координатам`?

Comment: Нет, потому что каждый следующий вывод смещается относительно первого вывода. canvas.translate(200,100) смещает вывод на эти координаты, относительно предыдущего вывода. Может есть какие-то другие методы? Например как у вывода точки canvas.drawPoint(x,y,p).

Comment: @kaaa Можно после вывода картинки сделать обратное смещение canvas.translate(-200, -100); Так вы вернетесь в исходную точку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способ 1

```
    Picture picture = mas_S[0];
    int pictureWidth = picture.getWidth();
    int pictureHeight = picture.getHeight();
    Rect rect = new Rect(100, 200, 100 + pictureWidth, 200 + pictureHeight);
    canvas.drawPicture(picture, rect);
```

Способ 2

```
    canvas.translate(200, 100);
    canvas.drawPicture(mas_S[0]);
    canvas.translate(-200, -100);
```

В итоге вы вернетесь в исходную точку `canvas`.

Comment: Ответы правильные, но я хотел какой-то одной операцией решить проблему. Дело в том, что рисовать придется много и каждый раз расставлять картинки таким образом боюсь будет "тормозить" приложение. Пока не буду отмечать, что ответ дан, подожду еще. Если никто больше не предложит лучший вариант, то отмечу этот.

Comment: @kaaa, тормозить не будет, если картинка закеширована в памяти. Вам дали верный ответ. Ваш не работает, т.к. вы каждый раз делаете смещение на вектор методом translate.

Comment: А как закешировать картинки в память?

Comment: @kaaa Например, так: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/